# Activities standard component UI is changed with spring 23 release

Tags: lightning-experience, css, lightning-design-system, static-resources, spring23

We have standard activities component on record page. The UI for that component is as below for scratch org which does not yet have Spring 23 release:

[image]

As salesforce spring 23 release coming we have our product setup on pre release org. The activity standard component is being displayed as below:

[image]

I was having challenges understanding what might be causing this change as we are using standard salesforce component on record page. Anyone got any information or suggestion around this.

Comment: Is this standard component.

Comment: Yes it is standard component we are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can edit the activities timeline component on the lighting record page. There is a checkbox "use tabbed activity view", which restores the old UI.

Comment: And you have to do this everywhere you use the Activities component.

Answer (score 2):

As per Spring '23 [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sales_productivity_activity_composer.htm&type=5&release=242) this is expected behaviour. This is related to Dynamic activity composer which gives reps activities at the click of a button and offers more choices than the tabbed activity composer.

I did not find any information related to disabling this feature at this moment. I will update this thread if I find any.